# Events Calendar to display on front end

Tags: civievent, joomla, calendar

I have a joomla built website I have installed civicrm into.  I would like to display an events calendar (not just the events list) on the front end.  I have tried installing the available extensions that civicrm list, but those only appear to be for the back end of the civicrm component.  Is there something that can be integrated with the events portion of civicrm and display in calendar format on the front end?

(Ed) I have tried these that can be found in the available extensions list: com.agiliway.civicalendar com.osseed.eventcalendar Both are only for the back end.

Comment: pls list the extensions you have tried

Comment: I have tried these that can be found in the available extensions list:
com.agiliway.civicalendar
com.osseed.eventcalendar

Both are only for the back end.

Comment: I have done this before on Drupal with the civicalendar. You need to give CMS permission for the civicalendar to be displayed for anonymous user and then edit the template page in the extension to make it look the way you want.

Answer (score 2):

com.osseed.eventcalendar can be used to display a calendar in the frontend of your Joomla-site by following the instructions in the readme.txt of the extension.

1. Copy the folder "yourextensiondirectory/com.osseed.eventcalendar/joomla/EventCalendar" to "joomlarootdirectory/components/com_civicrm/views/" which will add the menu item type for Event Calendar.
2. For frontend display you need to add a menu item of the type "Event calendar" and provide the calendar id (if you have multiple calendars). If you pass an empty ID it will display the global calendar for frontend.